# Eliminating one variable from two simple polynomial equations

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, eliminate

Is this really that hard to eliminate variable `t`? It runs forever without any result.

$$x=-\frac{t (2 t+1)}{4 t^5+1},u=-\frac{2 t}{t^2+1}$$

```
Eliminate[{x == -((t (1 + 2 t))/(1 + 4 t^5)), u == -((2 t)/(1 + t^2))}, t]
```

Manually I got in few seconds this result (maybe it is not complete):

```
-4 u^4 + 5 u^5 + 64 u x - 64 u^2 x - 56 u^3 x + 46 u^4 x + 4 u^5 x - 128 x^2 + 160 u^2 x^2 - 40 u^4 x^2 + 17 u^5 x^2 == 0
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `GroebnerBasis[]` to begin with? `GroebnerBasis[{x == -((t  (1 + 2  t))/(1 + 4  t^5)), u == -((2  t)/(1 + t^2))}, {x, y}, t]`

Comment: Yes I can do several other things too. But from the name of the function `Eliminate` it is clear why I used it. It is even stranger that `GroebnerBasis` works in this case because it is meant to work on polynomials. The input is not in the polynomial form and more it is in the form of equations. It should be the other way around. `Eliminate` should manage to solve equations not `GroebnerBasis`.

Comment: Just to compare. The command of Maple 2018 `eliminate({u = -2*t/(t^2+1), x = -t*(1+2*t)/(4*t^5+1)}, t)` results in `{t = -u*(u^3*x-2*u^3-16*u^2*x+32*x)/(4*u^4*x+u^4-4*u^3-48*u^2*x+64*x)}, {17*u^5*x^2+4*u^5*x-40*u^4*x^2+5*u^5+46*u^4*x-4*u^4-56*u^3*x+160*u^2*x^2-64*u^2*x+64*u*x-128*x^2}` in a moment.

Answer (score 6):

Since you want an implicit equation in `x` and `u`... get rid of the denominators

```
Eliminate[{x(1+4t^5)==-t(1+2t),u(1+t^2)==-2t},t]
```

which INSTANTLY returns

```
-4*u^4 + 5*u^5 + 64*u*x - 64*u^2*x - 56*u^3*x + 46*u^4*x + 4*u^5*x -
128*x^2 + 160*u^2*x^2 - 40*u^4*x^2 + 17*u^5*x^2 == 0
```

which is EXACTLY the result you got by hand, so I assume your manual method
also eliminated the denominators, without deeply considering consequences.

If I look at the denominators then it looks like those can be zero when t== -1/2 or t==0 and neither of those seem, after a few seconds of thought, to be a problem for your solution.

General rule that widely applies: Denominators hard, make denominators go away

Comment: Denominators are very simple too... That can not be the reason to fail the computation. There is some bug in their algorithm.

Comment: @azerbajdzan, please note the last bullet point in the documentation for `Eliminate`: _Eliminate works primarily with **linear and polynomial equations**._

Comment: "primarily" - that explains why they used equations with `Sqrt` or `Sin` in documentation of `Eliminate`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Eliminate[{u == -((2 t)/(1 + t^2)), x == -((t (1 + 2 t))/(1 + 4 t^5))},
           t, Mode -> Modular]
(* -4 u^4 + 5 u^5 + 64 u x - 64 u^2 x - 56 u^3 x + 46 u^4 x + 4 u^5 x - 
   128 x^2 + 160 u^2 x^2 - 40 u^4 x^2 + 17 u^5 x^2 == 0 *)
```

Comment: There is no sense in using `Mode -> Modular` if you are not trying to find a solution over some modulus - which I was not. The solution should be found without it.

Comment: @azerbajdzan, you cannot claim that there is _"a bug"_ and that _"it is really embarrassing for Mathematica"_ if you are expecting functions to work differently than explained in the documentation. However, I certainly agree that you could bring this to thea attention of WRI, because it is clear that `Eliminate` **can** solve your problem, albeit with a somehow unexpected option `Modulus`. They may have an explanation, update the documentation, or feel that they can make the function work without this. However, note that `Eliminate` is quite an old function ...

Comment: ... that has not been updated for [quite a while](https://www.youtube.com/live/xCfgcrL9Rcc?t=1633).

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Reduce[
  {x == -((t (1 + 2 t))/(1 + 4 t^5)), u == -((2 t)/(1 + t^2))}, 
  x, {t}] // Simplify
```

[image]

```
Reduce[
  {x == -((t (1 + 2 t))/(1 + 4 t^5)), u == -((2 t)/(1 + t^2))}, 
  x, {t}, Reals] // Simplify
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the answer? You should get the polynomial you can see in my question. I am not interested in solving for `x`. I need implicit equation in `x` and `u`.

Comment: Seeing your answer I guess `Eliminate` did not work even in the latest version of Mathematica. But that is really embarrassing for Mathematica. Such a simple task... and if I am not mistaken they claimed huge speed increase in polynomial manipulation and eliminating of variables in version 13 (or was it version 11?).

Comment: @azerbajdzan - `x == f[u]` is an implicit equation for x and u. Plotting these implicit equations would include @Domen solution as well as some additional curve elements.

Comment: The question is about finding implicit polynomial equation in `x` and `u` - i.e. finding `f(x,u)==0`  where function `f` is polynomial or ratio of two polynomials.

Comment: Then I recommend that you edit your question to clarify your intent. As currently posed it merely requests the removal of the variable `t`

Comment: My question is formulated correctly. There are already two answers that confirm this.